# 404 status code in response from Cloudfront for a single page react application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

we have a single page app in ReactJS that is being served by CloudFront but the response status continues to be 404 for any nested pages (i.e pages other than the home page).

How can this be resolved? Attached snapshot

[image]

Comment: Seems like an issue with Credentials. Did you double check them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can catch an error like 404 and redirect it to 200 and your index.html with custom error pages in cloudfront like shown here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gBkysF8_-Es